# Concat string in the middle of another String, skipping the last

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to transform this String "23 março 2019" into "23 de março de 2019".

I did the way below and it works, but I have to type a lot to get rid of the 'in case first' "de".

```
String strDate = splitted[0];
        var fullDate = strDate
            .split(" ")
            .map((s) => " de " + s)
            .join()
            .trim()
            .split(' ')
            .skip(1)
            .join(' ');
```

Is there a way to simplify this expression maybe doing the equivalent to (skipLast function doesn't exits):

```
var fdate = strDate.split(" ").map((s) => s+" de ").skipLast().join();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try replacing the blank spaces with your value, like this:

```
final data = "23 março 2019";
final result = data.replaceAll(" ", " de ");
print(result);
```